# Creating a sequence convergent to $l$ in space $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let us suppose $S$ is an infinite subset of space $X$, and $l$ is its limit point. In other words, every open set containing $l$ contains points from $S\setminus \{l\}$.

How can we define a sequence $\langle x_n\rangle\in S$ such that it converges to $l$? Please note that $X$ is not necessarily a metric space.

A sequence is convergent in a topological space to $l$ when for every open set $G$ containing $l$, there is a positive integer $N(G)$ such that $\forall i>N(G), x_i\in G$.

It doesn't strike me that we can claim there necessarily exist nested open sets containing $l$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Spaces where such a sequence exists whenever $l$ is a limit point of $S$ are called *Fréchet-Urysohn spaces* (FU spaces). Not each $FU$-space is first countable, for example the wedge of infinitely many circles is FU but not first-countable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is not first countable, then it can be that there is no *sequence* in $S$ converging to $l$, consider $X = [0,\,\omega_1]$ where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, and $S = [0,\, \omega_1)$. $\omega_1$ is a limit point of $S$, but no sequence in $S$ converges to $\omega_1$, since the supremum of countably many countable ordinals is countable.

If $X$ is first countable, let $U_1 \supset U_2 \supset \dotsb$ a countable neighbourhood basis of $l$, and choose $x_n \in U_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I have one simple example in mind. 'If X is not first countable, then it can be that there is no sequence in S converging to l'. 
In (R, cocountable topology) every rational no. is limit point of set A of all irrational no. But as only convergent sequences are eventually constant. No sequence with entries from A converges to a rational no.